# Show all html triggered by javascript selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using selenium to scrape this website: https://osdr.nasa.gov/bio/repo/data/studies/OSD-385

Now the problem arises with the files section. I want to scrape all the names of the files in that section, but to do that I need to click all  tags inside the div. The problem is that some  tag might be hidden and to show it I must click on another  tag that is also hidden.
How can I automate this process, and solve this problem?

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML of _the names of the files in that section_, _all tags inside the div_ and _tag might be hidden_